# why does bearer token gives error "Cannot read property 'split' of undefined"?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios, bearer-token

All im trying to do here is to protect express route..
here sending request from react to express router:

```
Axios.post("http://localhost:5000/users/userinfo/" + this.state.id, {
      headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + "jsonwebtoken" },
      data:{this.state.data},
    })
      .then((res) => console.log(res.data))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

now this request hits the express router:

```
router.post("/userinfo/:id", verifyToken, (req, res) => {
  res.json({ msg: "authorized", data: req.payback });
)}
```

Here is the verfifyToken middleware:

```
module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
  try {
    const decode = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1];
    req.token = decode;

    jwt.verify(req.token, process.env.JWT_SECRET, (err, data) => {
      if (!err) {
        req.payback = data;
        next();
      } else {
        return res.json({ error: "Unauthorized User!" });
      }
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.json({ error: error });
  }
};
```

but this gives me error:  *TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined*

It works fine with postman but when i send request from react it keeps repeating this error i'm stuck here please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`axios.post`](https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosposturl-data-config) has the following signature `axios#post(url[, data[, config]])`

So you have to do the following instead.

```js
Axios.post("http://localhost:5000/users/userinfo/" + this.state.id, 
  this.state.data, {
    headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + "jsonwebtoken" },
  })
```

Also, if you only want one header field, it's better to use [`req.get()`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.get) or the alias `req.header` to avoid case mismatch

```js
req.header('Authorization')
```

Comment: i have tried it too but same error again.. HOW is this undefined!!

Comment: @MuhammadUsman can you confirm the request from axios is sent correctly? Did you inspect the request with the browsers devtool?